# Are FIPS certified algorithms in .net framework backward compatible?

Tags: fips

Our software is based on .net framework 4.5. We are making our application `FIPS` compliant. So we are replacing the older classes with `FIPS` compliant classes.

```
MD5CryptoServiceProvider -> SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
RijndaelManaged -> AesCryptoServiceProvider
```

But we have certain data in our database which are encrypted with older algorithm. How do I retrieve them, as we are now using newer algorithms? Are the newer algorithms backward compatible?

Thanks

Comment: There's no such thing as *"FIPS compliant"*. You either use FIPS ***Validated*** cryptography, or you don't. I know the DHS pulled a bunch of network switches from US Federal because a marketing department said the same thing. They were not restored until the company stated they provided FIPS Validated cryptography.

Answer (score 2):

> we have certain data in our database which are encrypted with older algorithm. How do I retrieve them, as we are now using newer algorithms

Upsize the data. Rather than storing just `MD5(data)`, add an extra column to the table called `upsized`. If `upsized = false`, then calculate `SHA256(MD5(data))` and store it. Finally, set `upsized = true`.

There's some small/trivial technical defects in the construction, but it gets you past the C&A requirements of FIPS 140-2 and the SP800-53 audit.